# Is there a way to render a different template based on current user without using conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two different layouts, one is completely custom and the other is bootstrap. For admins we want to render a bootstrap view and for non-admins we render it normally. For the most part this is pretty straight forward because admins and users don't share many views -- but there are some.

My original idea involved overriding `render` so that it would check if there's a bootstrap version of a file. So for example there would be `_user.html.erb` and `_user.bootstrap.html.erb` which would have bootstrap specific templating.

I'd like to not modify any controllers so ideally, something like `render 'form'` would behave smartly and check if there's an `_form.bootstrap.html.erb`, and if there isn't it would fallback to `_form.html.erb`

### First attempt

My first attempt looked something like this

```
# I don't think this is the actual method signature of render
def render(options=nil, extra_options, &block)
  # if it should render bootstrap and options is a string and there exists a bootstrap version
  #   set it up to render the bootstrap view
  super(options, extra_options, &b)
end
```

### Current attempt

I'm thinking about registering a template that basically checks if a file exists and then uses erb. I haven't made any progress towards this yet.

Comment: Have you considered using namespaces to separate views and controllers?

Comment: @Swards yes but then I'd still have to call render with a folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is how I did it:

This is set in the application controller, with a `before_filter :render_bootstrap`

```
def render_bootstrap
  return unless bootstrap?
  new_action = "#{self.action_name}.bootstrap"
  has_bs_view = template_exists?(new_action,params[:controller],false) ||  template_exists?(new_action,params[:controller], true)
  if has_bs_view
    self.action_name = new_action
  end
end
```

I decided to extend this even further so that inside of a view like `show.bootstrap.html.erb` you can still use `render "form"` without doing `render "form.bootstrap"`. This was done by overwriting the rails render helper.